# Calling an ActionSheet from a TabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbar, uiactionsheet

I have a tab bar with 4 buttons (Home, Visits, Share, More). I want the "Share" button in my tab bar to call an actionsheet which has the appropriate buttons to select the particular channels I want the user to be able to distribute links to the app (Facebook, Twitter, Email, etc.).

I'm able to do this using Storyboard but I have to create a unique (blank) view controller that is linked to the "Share" button in the tab bar. I put the following code within the viewDidAppear method to display the actionsheet when the "Share" button is selected:

```
int selectedTab = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;

if (selectedTab == 2)
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share Your Visit with Friends!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook", @"Twitter", @"Email eduLaunchpad", nil];

    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
}
```

When I close the actionsheet, I then return by default to the home view:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

While this works, it isn't optimal from a user perspective. I would prefer the actionsheet to appear over the particular view that was displaying when the "Share" button was selected. For example, if the user was on the "Visits" view and selected "Share" from the tab bar, I would like the actionsheet to appear over the top of the visits view with that view being visible behind the actionsheet.

Am I able to achieve this using Storyboard? Or do I need a custom tab bar in order to implement this functionality? If a custom tab bar is required, I would appreciate some guidance/insight into how to implement that including the custom tab bar as well as the actionsheet from the tab bar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this, too, googled around, and eventually built the following category on UITabBarController.

The trick to getting the action sheet to appear on the current tab is that you never want to actually visit that action-sheet-presenting tab.  Cover the tab bar in that position with a UIButton which initiates the action sheet.

Paint your tab bar as you normally would in storyboard, leaving an empty bar item at the position where the special behavior is to occur.  Then add this category...

```
//  UITabBarController+Button.h

@interface UITabBarController (Button) <UIActionSheetDelegate>
- (void)replaceItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withButtonImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage;
@end

//  UITabBarController+Button.m

#import "UITabBarController+Button.h"

#define kBUTTON_TAG   4096

@implementation UITabBarController (Button)

- (void)replaceItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withButtonImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:kBUTTON_TAG];

    if (!button) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.tag = kBUTTON_TAG;
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UITabBar *bar = self.tabBar;
        CGFloat width = bar.frame.size.width / bar.items.count;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(index*width, bar.frame.origin.y, width, bar.frame.size.height);

        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Handle button tap

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Sheet:"
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Action A", @"Action B", @"Action C", nil];

    [sheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBar];
}
```

Call it with an index < tabBar.items.count and an image for the button.  If it's your app's root vc, you can call it as follows:

```
#import "the category i suggest above"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // whatever else you do in here, then
    NSLog(@"%@", self.window.rootViewController);  // make sure this is a UITabBarController
    // if it is, then ...
    UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tbc replaceItemAtIndex:2 withButtonImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some image name"]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: danh, thanks for the assistance. I'm working thru your code but am a Noob so I appreciate your patience as I work through this. Can you talk me through "Call it with an index < tabBar.items.count and an image for the button."

Comment: Sure thing - that index indicates which position on the tab bar to place the button.  I'm just saying you shouldn't ask for a position that doesn't exist.  e.g. 0 will be the leftmost, 1 - next to that, and so on.  But your tab bar has only N items, the max index you can ask for is N-1 or tabBar.items.count-1.

Comment: Just reread your question... to make the share tab into a button, you should call it with index==2.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I set the index to 2 since it was the third button in my tab bar.

One other thing. I'm dragging the tab bar controller from the "Objects" menu in storyboard so I'm not able to add a third button to the tab bar without an associated view controller. Is there a trick to adding an unassociated button that I'm not aware of or are you creating your tab bar programmatically?

Comment: I supplied code that creates the button.  Just paste it into new .h and .m files and call it when app inits.

Comment: Thanks, danh, both for your assistance and patience. I saw the code for creating the button and spacing within the tab bar so I guess calling the tab bar when the app inits is what is confusing me. When using a tab bar controller in storyboard, the initialization is handled auto-magically - I don't have to manually do that so how and where would I do that? In AppDelegate under 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'?

Comment: Yes that should work if it's the root VC.  Double check in that method with NSLog(@"%@", self.window.rootViewController):  If you see your tabBarController there, then, it's good to go.  Will edit my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Dude, you're going to kill me...So, my NSLog output shows UITabBarController is the root view controller and I've placed the code in AppDelegate.m. However, I'm receiving the following error on [tbc replaceItemAtIndex:2…] when running: !No visible @interface for 'UITabBarController' declares  the selector 'replaceItemAtIndex:withButtonImage:'. I made AppDelegate.h a <UITabBarControllerDelegate> thinking that might have been the issue, but no luck. I think it is looking for a view controller to put in position 2 of the tab bar and it can't find anything. Am I interpreting that error correctly?

Comment: No worries.  I think the problem may be the category declaration.  In objective-c, you can add behavior to an existing class -- in this case UITabBarController -- in what's called a category.  Please create a new class .h and .m file, naming them as I suggested "UITabBarController+Button.h" and "...m".  Replace any default contents of those files with the code I suggested, then import that into your app delegate.  Hopefully that will work.  Cheers.

Comment: When I create the class, the + is turned into an '_' so the class name is correct but the @interface declaration is UITabBarController_Button.  PS. This is getting to be a long thread, should I move this to chat?

Comment: SO says you don't have enough of a rep score to move to chat (I gave your question a +1 just now, but still not enough).  Xcode should allow + in the file names.  It might change the class names to have underscores, but just delete anything supplied by default and replace with the code I suggested.

Comment: OK, I'm an idiot. I wasn't creating a view controller for the SHARE option in storyboard, so the app was confused. It was trying to place a button in the 3rd position but there was no item there (I was trying to take a shortcut and only go with 3 view controllers until I had it working then add the fourth). As usual with coding - an ID10T error. *sigh* Your help has been invaluable - not only is the code working, but now I have something else to investigate in Objective-C: categories. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening actionsheet from tabbar

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

use this code.

```
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```